# Working with files in an object

Tags: python, file, oop

I have a design question. I'm doing an exercise in python (2.7) which is a simple game with a labyrinth. I need to read an write from a specific file every step of the game.

Currently I have 2 classes (Game and Labyrinth). The Labyrinth class is responsible for reading and writing the file.

My question is, is it ok to open the file in the **init** function of Labyrinth and close it at the end of the game within another function (which can be called from another class)? Or is it better to open and close the file every time?

The reason I don't save the file content into a string with `readlines()` is because I'm supposed to save to the file each step of the game.

Comment: If you change the files content by saving, you should reopen it for reading.

Comment: personally i prefer to pass `file_pointers` (meaning: `file_pointers=open(...)`) and pass those around.

Comment: The danger with separating the opening and closing like this is that errors arising can mean the file is never closed, which can erase the whole contents of your file. Do you have something in place to prevent this?

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: that's what I'm doing actually. But still, I need to close the file somewhere

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: I thought of calling the close function in a finally clause.

Comment: you are right; the answer by SuperBiasedMan explains how i usually do this: surround everything by a `with` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are at the design phase. 
So, you have to weigh the chances of losing your data due to some error or crash against the importance of your data and the cost of "protecting" it.

Using `with` protects you from some errors. If you consider that python itself may crash (e.g.), then you still have some risk. Saving after each step is evidently safer. How useful it is depends on the volume of saved data (and there are techniques for reducing this as well), the impact of each save on performance, and the chances of such crashes.

Without any further info, and simply guessing, my answer to your specific question:

> ... is it ok to open the file in the `init` function of `Labyrinth` and
>   close it at the end of the game...? Or is it better to open and close
>   the file every time?

is that *I would save after each step*.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the with open... statement every time I used the file.

Answer (score 2):

Though you could do this, it's generally recommended that you open files using `with` as that is designed to handle errors by closing the file no matter what happens. You can still pass it to your Labyrinth's `init` just by passing a reference.

```
with open(file) as f:
    labyrinth = Labyrinth(f)
```

Then if any error occurs, the file is still safely closed, and you've also passed your open file to the Labyrinth object anyway.

Comment: The Labyrinth class first copies the original file and then works on the copy. I could maybe do that from a function in the Labyrinth class (whether it's init or another function)

Comment: @onTheDev Yeah, that's typically how I handle it with things like writing a logging function.

Comment: I ended using the "with open" statement but in each function that uses the file.